# create chat plugin as external link

Tags: javascript, node.js

hello guys is there any way to reader popup chat window for website  1 to website 2 eg : suppose my domain name is https://test.com and i just want to provide them link or some piece of code. so they can add that in this own web site and my chat popup window is visible to that guys website . i had create chat popup window using html now my problem is that how i can give client 5-10 lines of code so that chat window is visible to client website. like chat plugin

Comment: i supposed, that it's must be script for client side, am i right?

Comment: @MykolaKikets yes or any other possible way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok... So let me explain, how that system actually works... (from my perspective...)

So... most of those websites saying that you need to do 1 of 2 things:
1. add this to the end of the body

```html
 <script src="https://test.com/plugin/chat.js?API=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

or
2. add script and some div in which this chat will be rendered

```html
<div id="futuristic-chat something-else bla-bla"></div>
<script src="https://test.com/plugin/chat.js?API=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

All those variants is server based. Why? Because of security reason.

***But how they know which data i want? Or how do they know my company name?***

All that is known by API key that you add to link...

***How that looks like on server side?***

It can be done in many ways, but most common is Server Render.
For example:

We have express server which handles special link:

```js
var app = require('express')();
...
app.get("/api/plugin/chat",(req,res) => {
...
});
```

client requests link with script:

```html
 <script src="https://test.com/api/plugin/chat?API=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

so on express we can get api key by `req.query.API`...
from this moment its only your imagination...
you can have a template file where we need to replace some string with api key:

```js
var app = require('express')();
const fs = require('fs');
...
app.get("/api/plugin/chat",(req,res) => {
...
let fileStr = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/file.js');
fileStr = fileStr.replace('{apiKeyHere}',req.query.API)
...
});
```

after building your file at the end don't forget to send as responce:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/javascript')
res.send(fileStr);
res.end();
```

So... That's how they works...
How it will looks like on your website, it's only question to you...

Comment: thanks I try and let you know weather it work or not